# C# P/Invoke keyboard_event

Tags: c#, pinvoke, keypress

I have been using some P/Invoke code to simulate a key press, but I can't work out how to press more than one key at once. I am trying to simulate pressing and holding CTRL and then pressing C and then V, so just a copy and paste.

The code I am using so far is this, but so far I can only manage to press CTRL, not hold it and press C and V:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

public const int VK_LCONTROL = 0xA2;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   keybd_event(VK_LCONTROL, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: By the Way: The last parameter is a `UIntPtr`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `dwFlags` controls if the key is released or not.

Try the following:

```
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, 0, 0);// presses ctrl
keybd_event(0x43, 0, 0, 0); // presses c
keybd_event(0x43, 0, 2, 0); //releases c
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, 2, 0); //releases ctrl
```

Answer (score 4):

keybd_event should be called twice for each keystroke, once to press it down, and once to release it, with the third argument including the bit KEYEVENTF_KEYUP. You should of course press both keys down before releasing either. See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxcompact/thread/d5d6097e-f221-452e-8b65-5659e2c9faaa) for a working example of pressing "SHIFT+TAB" using keybd_event on the .NET Compact Framework (may be slight differences).

Note that keybd_event has been superseded by [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but should still work.

Comment: +1 `SendInput` is rather more tricky to call. Easier to stick to `keybd_event`.